# Centered "go to top" image link, but the link is applied to 100% of the width of the height of the image

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, line

```
<a href="#body1"> <img  class="hdp" src="hdp.jpg" alt=""  title="top"/></a>
```

That was the html, and...

```
img.hdp{display:block;margin: 0 auto;border:none;padding:0;}
```

that's the css.

Well, the image links it to the top all right, the problem is the whole line of width to the left and right of the image does link it too. I've tried multiple solutions but none seems to work.
 Anyone who has an idea is welcomed to state it.

Comment: Huh? You're wrapping your entire image in an anchor tag...that's going to make everything inside that anchor tag a "link".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about move the class to the anchor, and give it a fixed with:

```
<a class="hdp" href="#body1"> <img  class="hdp" src="http://placehold.it/120x120" alt=""  title="top"/></a>
```

css:

```
a.hdp{ display:block;margin: 0 auto;border:none;padding:0; width: 120px;}
```

This assumes you know the width of the image in advance.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7pNMQ/1/